# PDO ignoring the given hostname

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wrote a super simple PDO connection:

```
const DB_HOST = '185.113.196.xxx';
const DB_USER = 'wesley';
const DB_PASS = 'th1s1s4p4ssw0rd';
const DB_NAME = 'flash';


try {
    $connection = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', DB_HOST, DB_NAME), DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

This all seems well and good, but when I actually execute a query, the following error pops up:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'wesley'@'12-123-12-123.ip.xs4all.nl' (using password: YES)
```

12.123.12.123 is our Office IP address (in this example), and 12-123-12-123.ip.xs4all.nl is our hostname. How in the world is it possible that that's the address it tries to connect to, instead of the given host?

Comment: does that user have access to that db on that host?

Comment: @treyBake Yeah, and I can connect to the host with the same credentials through workbench

Comment: I would say you are looking at one PHP file and running another

Comment: @YourCommonSense Confirmed that I'm not

Comment: wait. everything is correct. 12-123-12-123.ip.xs4all.nl is not the address it tries to connect to. let me find a relevant dupe

Comment: @aynber `Connection is: mysql:host=185.113.196.xxx;dbname=flash`

Comment: *facepalm* The connection string is correct. The issue is your mysql account. It's seeing **your** IP as `12-123-12-123.ip.xs4all.nl`. So check what hosts `wesley` can connect from in `mysql.user`. `SELECT user, host from mysql.user WHERE user = 'wesley'`